# Reverse Words with exclusion rules like anagrams and numbers

Tags: swift

Need some help!

I have a model function in a simple project for reversing words.

The questions is:

---

First - How can I reverse my words (sentences) to make an anagram? For example, I need to shift the first character in each reversed word on two positions by forward.
Example:

> Original - Hello world
>
> Reversed with anagrams: - lloeH lrdow

---

Second - How can I reverse my words (sentences) without numbers inside it?
Example:

> Original - Hello world 1234
>
> Reversed without numbers - olleH dlrow 1234

---

How can I do it in my code?

```
import Foundation

class ReverseWords {
    
    public func reverse(textField: String) -> String {
        
        if textField.isEmpty {
            return ""
        }
        
        return textField.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
            .components(separatedBy: " ")
            .map { String ( $0.reversed() ) }
            .joined(separator: " ")
    }
}
```

---

Comment: Where does the requirement for Swift 5.7 come in? Could you give us an example of what feature/area of 5.7 that is required for this?

Comment: Actually, I have'nt no requirements for swift 5.7 :)
But, swift 5.7 is latest release of swift :)
Maybe you have any suggestion how to do it in swift 5 / 5.7…? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out.

```
func anagram(sentence: String, separator: Character = " ") -> String {
    sentence
        .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        .split(separator: separator)
        .map { $0.contains(where: { $0.isNumber }) ? String($0) : String($0).reverseAndShift() }
        .joined(separator: String(separator))
}

extension String {
    func reverseAndShift(by offset: Int = 2) -> String {
        var reversed = Array(reversed())

        if let firstElement = reversed.first, offset < reversed.count {
            reversed.removeFirst()
            reversed.insert(firstElement, at: offset)
        }

        return String(reversed)
    }
}
```

`print(anagram(sentence: "Hello world"))` -> `lloeH lrdow`

`print(anagram(sentence: "Hello world 1234"))` -> `lloeH lrdow 1234`

Comment: Done!!! Great solution!! Works great!!! 
I hope, it will help everyone who started to learn Swift! :) Thank you for the tip!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

It’s helpful to break your problem into independently testable functions.

Here are two functions you should find useful:

```
func shift2(_ str: String) -> String {
    guard str.count > 2 else { return str }

    let first = str.prefix(1)
    let secondthird = str.prefix(3).suffix(2)
    let end = String(str.dropFirst(3))

    return secondthird + first + end
}

func reverseWord(_ str: String) -> String {
    guard Set(str).intersection(Set("0123456789")).isEmpty else { return str }

    return String(str.reversed())
}
```

### Examples

```
print(shift2("abcde"))
print(shift2("abc"))
print(shift2("ab"))
```

> ```
> bcade
> bca
> ab
> ```

```
print(reverseWord("Hello"))
print(reverseWord("Hello1"))
print(reverseWord("12345"))
```

> ```
> olleH
> Hello1
> 12345
> ```

Comment: Hi **vacawama**! :)

   " guard str.length > 2 else { return str } " 
Told me that - " Value of type 'String' has no member 'length' " 

I replaced it to " .count ": ->

   " guard str.count > 2 else { return str } "

Works great!!! :)

Thank you for the solution!!! :)

Comment: I tested it on an older version of Swift and it worked.  Thanks for letting me know.